# xslt:sort with lookup condition

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to sort TranHist nodes by paymentRecordDate, then by the account balance.

My xml is as follows:

```
<data>
    <Account>
          <accountNumber>12345</accountNumber>
          <balance>1400</balance>
    </Account>
    <Account>
          <accountNumber>6789</accountNumber>
          <balance>2000</balance>
    </Account>
    <TranHist>
          <accountNumber>12345</accountNumber>
          <paymentStatus>CL</paymentStatus>
          <paymentRecordDate>20141101</paymentRecordDate>
    </TranHist>
    <TranHist>
          <accountNumber>12345</accountNumber>
          <paymentStatus>CL</paymentStatus>
          <paymentRecordDate>20141201</paymentRecordDate>
    </TranHist>
    <TranHist>
          <accountNumber>6789</accountNumber>
          <paymentStatus>1</paymentStatus>
          <paymentRecordDate>20141201</paymentRecordDate>
    </TranHist>
<data>
```

The xslt I have so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="accounts" select="data/Account"/>

<xsl:for-each select="data/TranHist">
    <xsl:sort select="number(paymentRecordDate)" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="$accounts[accountNumber = ????/accountNumber]/balance" order="descending" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How do I reference the the accountNumber in the TransHist node of the for-each context?

Comment: Have you tried `$accounts[accountNumber = ./accountNumber]` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. accountNumber and ./accountNumber are equivalent so it is comparing accounts/accountNumber to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I reference the the accountNumber in the TransHist node of the
>   for-each context?

The best way to do this is by using a **key**. Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="acct" match="Account" use="accountNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="data/TranHist">
            <xsl:sort select="paymentRecordDate" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="key('acct', accountNumber)/balance" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. It also seems to work for composite keys e.g.

     <xsl:key name="acct" match="Account" use="concat(accountNumber,accountType)" />

Comment: @AntonK Yes, it does - but it would be best to insert a separator such as '|' between the concatenated values, to prevent false positive matches.